# Using a GitHub library in Android Studio

Tags: android

G'day! I seem to have imported a library from GitHub (https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib) to "dependencies", but when I tried:

```
import com.leff.midi.MidiFile;
```

It still doesn't know what leff is. How do I know whether I've successfully imported the library, please? And how can I use it in my code? Thank you.

Comment: I think you have a good tutorial here. You may have tried this. https://www.androidauthority.com/add-a-github-library-to-android-studio-using-maven-jcenter-jitpack-777050/#:~:text=Open%20the%20project%20where%20you,repository%2C%20then%20click%20'OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files ^^

Answer (score 1):

That imports the file during compilation.  You still need to add the dependency in the build system, or it won't know where to look for the file.  Assuming a standard gradle build, you need to add it to the build.gradle file.  Look for the dependencies section for an example, you need to know what version of the library, the name of the library, and the nae of the target within it in whatever package repository you're using.

If instead you mean you downloaded the source and tried to build it that way, you still need a dependency, you just need to make it a local one and not a remote.